# Animating stills in After Effects

Tags: video, after-effects, animation, motion

I did a short corporate composition that used alot of stills. I animated alot of the stills by zooming in and out and panning across. Pretty basic. I have trouble with unexpected movements when I animate both scale and position of the image. These are little sudden changes of position of that happen at the end of the movement. How can I control these animations better? I will try to post a sample of what I mean if this question is not clear.

Comment: Good idea! If it's possible, you should add an image(s) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience all unexpected movements when keyframing are fixed by editing bezier curves of those keyframes, make them linear or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting your keyframes, right-clicking them, and clicking "edit interpolation", then changing it from "Bezier" to "linear", and all the variations therein.

Also try making doubly sure that your keyframes are aligned properly on the timeline.